# Where does xfce-panel load plugins and their .desk files

Tags: plugins, xfce

I have written one simple xfce4 plugin, it works very well on my Debian computer.

On Debia 8, the `.so` and `.desktop` file are located at `/usr/lib/xfce4/panel-plugins` and `/usr/share/xfce4/panel-plugins` directories respectively.

However, When I tested it on Fedora 24, `.so` and `.desktop` files are placed in `/usr/lib64/xfce4/panel/plugins/` and `/usr/share/xfce4/panel/plugins/`.

So, for portable reason, how do I find the right location to place these two files in different Linux distribution.

Comment: I have no answer for you,but on latest Ubuntu, they seem to be at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/panel/plugins`.